# Problems installing NIFI 1.14.0 on an EC2

Tags: apache-nifi

I install Java after nifi . In nifi properties I edit the nifi.web.https.host field with the instance's private IP. I start up Nifi. I look at the log that came up. And I put the public IP in the browser.And this error message appears.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If NiFi is running, the error looks to be related to the SSL/TLS certificate.

What if you tried using the Public IP rather than the private IP? Could it be an issue with the firewall?

I would check to verify that the TLS/SSL configuration is correct.